Transform table data into json variant column
We have a common transactional table in which history data is loaded every day through standard pipes then processing the data (batch processing) using streams, tasks, procedures onto this final table. Now the company changes the way of loading data turning into using kafka connect that creates a raw table reading the avro messages that are published into the topic.
This raw table created by kafka connector automatically has variant columns, particularly one of this in the form:
[
   {
      "transactionDetailId": 112233445566,
      "brandCode": "31137209",
      "transactionOrigin": "Origin 1",
      "installmentCreditTransactionId": 1,
      ...
   },
   {
      "transactionDetailId": 112233445566,
      "brandCode": "31137209",
      "transactionOrigin": "Origin 1",
      "installmentCreditTransactionId": 2,
   },
   ...
 ]

This raw table created by kafka connect only has new data, since 2024-10-01 (yyyy-mm-dd) and history data is already loaded in this final table that already mentioned (processed data).
The challenge that i'm facing is to transform this history transactional table data into this variant columns. For other tables i've already been capable of transform this transactional data into variant columns using snowflake's function OBJECT_CONSTRUCT but for this table, and this column in particular the thing is that
{
          "transactionDetailId": 112233445566,
          "brandCode": "31137209",
          "transactionOrigin": "Origin 1",
          "installmentCreditTransactionId": 1,
          ...
       }

is one row in the final table and
{
          "transactionDetailId": 112233445566,
          "brandCode": "31137209",
          "transactionOrigin": "Origin 1",
          "installmentCreditTransactionId": 2,
       },

is another row.
The attribute that split this variant column is "installmentCreditTransactionId" so in this case those two objects transforms into two rows. Same if i go to the transactional table i would see for example:
transactionDetailId   brandCode   transactionOrigin   installmentCreditTransactionId
998877665544          55555555    Origin 2            1
998877665544          55555555    Origin 2            2
998877665544          55555555    Origin 2            3

That should be transform into:
   [
       {
          "transactionDetailId": 998877665544,
          "brandCode": "55555555",
          "transactionOrigin": "Origin 2",
          "installmentCreditTransactionId": 1,
          ...
       },
       {
          "transactionDetailId": 998877665544,
          "brandCode": "55555555",
          "transactionOrigin": "Origin 2",
          "installmentCreditTransactionId": 2,
       },
       {
          "transactionDetailId": 998877665544,
          "brandCode": "55555555",
          "transactionOrigin": "Origin 2",
          "installmentCreditTransactionId": 3,
       },
       ...
    ]

I don't see how only the OBJECT_CONSTRUCT would help here because how many installmentCreditTransactionId ids of each message is gonna be random.
Any thoughts on how to approach this? Using OBJECT_AGGR?
Edit 1: This is what i have so far:
SELECT 
    OBJECT_AGG(tab1.id_1::VARCHAR,
        OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
            'col1', null,
            'col2', tab1.col2::VARCHAR,
            'id_1', tab1.id_1::VARCHAR, -- one of the id's
            'id_2', tab1.id_2::VARCHAR, -- one of the id's
            'col3', COALESCE(tab1.col3::VARCHAR, '0'),
            'id_3', tab1.id_3::VARCHAR, -- one of the id's
            'col4', tab1.col4::VARCHAR,
            'id_4', tab1.id_4::VARCHAR, -- one of the id's
            'col5', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::VARCHAR,
            'col6', null) OVER (PARTITION BY tab1.id_1::VARCHAR, tab1.id_2::VARCHAR, tab1.id_3::VARCHAR, tab1.id_4::VARCHAR) AS result
FROM 
    db.schema.table1 tab1 
LEFT JOIN
    db.schema.table2 tab2
ON 
    ...
LEFT JOIN
    db.schema.table3 tab3
ON
    ...;

But is not returning what i need, is returning:
first row:
{
  "1": {
    "col1": "28031866",
    "col2": "524",
    "id_1": "1",
    "id_2": "46554737145",
    "col3": 0,
    "id_3": "39866",
    "col_4": "100",
    "id_4": "969424002",
    "col_5": "2025-03-13",
    "col_6": "2024-10-11"
  }
}

second row:
{
  "2": {
    "col1": "28031866",
    "col2": "522",
    "id_1": "2",
    "id_2": "46554737145",
    "col3": 0,
    "id_3": "39866",
    "col_4": "99",
    "id_4": "969424002",
    "col_5": "2024-11-13",
    "col_6": "2024-10-11"
  }
}

third row:
{
  "3": {
    "col1": "28031866",
    "col2": "522",
    "id_1": "3",
    "id_2": "46554737145",
    "col3": 0,
    "id_3": "39866",
    "col_4": "99",
    "id_4": "969424002",
    "col_5": "2025-01-15",
    "col_6": "2024-10-11"
  }
}

And what i need is like this:
[
   {
      "col1": "28031866",
      "col2": "522",
      "id_1": "1",
      "id_2": "46554737145",
      "col3": 0,
      "id_3": "39866",
      "col_4": "99",
      "id_4": "969424002",
      "col_5": "2025-01-15",
      "col_6": "2024-10-11"
   },
   {
      "col1": "28031866",
      "col2": "522",
      "id_1": "2",
      "id_2": "46554737145",
      "col3": 0,
      "id_3": "39866",
      "col_4": "99",
      "id_4": "969424002",
      "col_5": "2025-01-15",
      "col_6": "2024-10-11"
   },
   {
      "col1": "28031866",
      "col2": "522",
      "id_1": "3",
      "id_2": "46554737145",
      "col3": 0,
      "id_3": "39866",
      "col_4": "99",
      "id_4": "969424002",
      "col_5": "2025-01-15",
      "col_6": "2024-10-11"
   }
 ]

in one row. See how only the id_1 is the one that should aggregate everything in one row. But i don't understand how to achieve this

many rows to one is a AGGRation step, as you have identified. If you know you have fixed count, you can pull all the data into a single row, and static build objects, or the other step is to rank/filter the rows and push them though an aggregation filter.

@SimeonPilgrim i edit the post with what i have so far

so with some fake data, I would expect you build the objects you want in the array like:
with fake_data(transactionDetailId, brandCode, transactionOrigin, installmentCreditTransactionId) as (
    select * from values
    (998877665544, 55555555, 'Origin 2', 1),
    (998877665544, 55555555, 'Origin 2', 2),
    (998877665544, 55555555, 'Origin 2', 3)
)
select 
    *,
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT( 
        'transactionDetailId', transactionDetailId,
        'brandCode', brandCode,
        'transactionOrigin', transactionOrigin,
        'installmentCreditTransactionId', installmentCreditTransactionId) as obj
from fake_data
where true /*filters you care about here */


then aggregate those obj, and it turns out you want ARRAY_AGG
with fake_data(transactionDetailId, brandCode, transactionOrigin, installmentCreditTransactionId) as (
    select * from values
    (998877665544, 55555555, 'Origin 2', 1),
    (998877665544, 55555555, 'Origin 2', 2),
    (998877665544, 55555555, 'Origin 2', 3)
)
select 
    transactionDetailId,
    ARRAY_AGG(
        OBJECT_CONSTRUCT( 
            'transactionDetailId', transactionDetailId,
            'brandCode', brandCode,
            'transactionOrigin', transactionOrigin,
            'installmentCreditTransactionId', installmentCreditTransactionId)
        ) as result
from fake_data
where true /*filters you care about here */
group by 1 
order by 1;



Yes man, thank you very much, this is what i needed
